# Error using mysql update

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm having problem to update data. I used preparedstatement to pass values to this:

```
"UPDATE Employee SET  " + name + "  =  ?  WHERE Employee_ID  =  ?"
```

This is the exception, "`you have an error in your sql syntax`".

Comment: The exception is all about mysql statement.

Comment: probably name is a goofy string. post the full stack trace or the resulting sql.

Comment: You need to enclose that `name` field in back ticks.

Comment: What is the value of `name`?

Comment: @user1707592 Even if you add your code snippet that will be helpful to spot error.

Comment: The exception "you have an error in your sql syntax; check manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for  the right syntax to use near ' =  'Cocest' WHERE Employee_ID  = '2' ' at line 1.

Comment: @user1707592 please edit `full stacktrace` and `code` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given query the +**name**+ seems to be **variable** only then it must matches the **column name** in the underlying **table** as i have taken **Employee**.
If the column does not exists then it'll throw an exception.

```
"UPDATE Employee SET col_name(table column name) = ? Where Employee_Id = ?"
```